# Solve this first-order linear ordinary diff eq. using method of undetermined coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem here with using the method of undetermined coefficients.

I've never been good at picking the form of the particular solution especially when the particular form is in the homogeneous solution part.  Here is the problem:

$$
 -u'+xu=-3xe^{\frac{1}{2}(x^{2}-1)}-x^{3}e^{\frac{1}{2}(x^{2}-1)}
$$

solving the homogeneous part I get:

$$
u_{h} = Ae^{\frac{1}{2}(x^{2})}
$$

My guess at the form of the particular solution was this:

$$
u_{p} = Axe^{\frac{1}{2}(x^{2}-1)}+Bx^{3}e^{\frac{1}{2}(x^{2}-1)}
$$

plugging these into the diff eq for the **left hand side** i get:

$$
2 e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(x^2-1\right)} \left(x^2 (A+3 B)+A+B x^4\right)
$$

So given our **right hand side** there is no $ x^{4} $ term and there is no order 1 term.
this makes A and B = zero which is where i'm stuck and it makes me feel i need one of each term for my form of the particular solution.

$$
u_p = Ae^{\frac{1}{2} \left(x^2-1\right)} + Bxe^{\frac{1}{2} \left(x^2-1\right)}+Cx^{2}e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(x^2-1\right)}+Dx^{3}e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(x^2-1\right)}
$$

I think that now in this form has the $Ae^{\frac{1}{2} \left(x^2-1\right)}$ in it i need to multiply the whole thing by x? or just the first term?

Update:  So i tried using the $u_p$ shown above here by hand.  I used Mathematica to do the algebra and differentiation to make things faster.   Something weird happens at the end where the order 1 terms do not equal.  I think it is insolvable using method of undetermined coefficients?  Either that or I do in fact need to multiply by an x to get rid of the $Ae^{\frac{1}{2} \left(x^2-1\right)}$ term.

Any help steering me in the right direction is appreciated.
[image: By hand work of the longer form of u_p]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these first order differential equations we can use the integrating factor
$$
u\mathrm{e}^{-\int xdx} = \int f(x)\mathrm{e}^{-\int xdx} + \lambda
$$

where

$$
f(x) = 3x\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x^{2}-1\right)} +x^{3}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x^{2}-1\right)}
$$

If you need any further help. I can complete if need be.

Comment: Thank you for your help Chinny. Actually Wolfram Alpha uses some kinda of integrating factor as well.  Looks slightly different but i can follow what they're doing.   

I however am looking for a way do to this with the method of undetermined coefficients.   If it is possible.  It might be more work but that was my goal.

Comment: Chinny,  I have asked my professor of mathematics and he said undetermined coefficients is difficult because each time you take a derivative an x comes down so right away it is not apparent on how to do undetermined coefficients with a problem such as this.  He said the best option is to go with your suggestion by using an integrating fact.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries. I mean it was clearly the form for using the integrating factor, but since you mentioned a prior method that you wanted to use I wasn't to sure if you wanted to continue in this approach. But I am glad it works.